# How to use a custom directive inside a custom directive with require

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am quite fairly new to AngularJS so I hope it's quite understandable why I'm having difficulty with this problem.

First I created a custom directive which uses another custom directive angular plugin http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

```
'use strict';

require('../../../../vendor/angular-xeditable/xeditable.js');

angular.module('ft.core').directive('ftXeditableText', function() {

    var result = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/EditableText.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


        }
    };

    return result;
});
```

And this is my template file EditableText.html

```
<span editable-text="{{item.Name}}">
    {{item.Name}}
</span>
```

In my html code, it renders the resulting tag

```
<ft-xeditable-text item="ngModel[0]" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <span editable-text="XEditable Text" class="ng-binding">
        XEditable Text
    </span>
</ft-xeditable-text>
```

I can't seem to make the plugin work. It renders in the browser but the plugin's feature doesn't execute. How should I approach this? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to call anything in the link. Like element.Editable()? I need you to explain the problem more

Comment: It means I want to use the directive editable-text html attribute from another directive which will render the view EditableText.html